# How do I remove dried latex paint from clothing?

Tags: paint, cleaning

How do you remove dried latex paint out of clothes? It has been there for several days. I haven't really tried anything yet because didn't want to make it worse.

Comment: Depending on the fabric I would try lacquer thinner on cotton, waterless hand cleaner on more delicate fabrics

Comment: I've had luck with GoofOff

Answer (score 1):

I find that rubbing alcohol works quite well as a solvent for dried latex paint.  Soak and rub.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a lot depends on the fiber of the clothing in question and probably the paint as well. My experience is limited to cotton clothing (T-shirts). Rather surprisingly, a simple machine wash with regular detergent removed a mixture of acrylic (US "latex") wall paint, acrylic putty, gypsum and cement plaster. Honestly, I was extremely surprised regular detergent can remove all that. I suspect it's because cotton has a "puff" on its surface that gets removed (or turned into lint) by the washing cycle, together with whatever is stuck to it. With some lint-free artificial fibers, a simple machine wash might not work so well.

I have a relative who paints [paintings] with artist grade acrylics, and she says that those don't come off clothes well in the washing machine, so I suspect paint grade/type matter as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mötsenböcker's LIFT OFF Latex Paint Remover should work, and is readily available in North American big box stores and Amazon.

From their instructions:

**For Washables**

- Test for colorfastness by spraying an inconspicuous area.
- Spray paint spot thoroughly; wait at least 60 seconds.
- Agitate if necessary (the back end of a tooth brush works well).
  Repeat if necessary.
- Launder as fabric recommendations allow.

Comment: Which end of a toothbrush is the *back end*?  Is that the brush end or the handle?

Comment: I'd think they are talking about the handle. I've had success just rubbing the fabric against itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution I could find on online.  Nothing worked.  Finally, on a whim and out of desperation, I squirted on some Goof Off.  It took only very minimal effort with a toothbrush to remove the paint completely.

Answer (score 0):

Soap + HOT water can work sometimes. Hot water can break down latex paint. I would always try this before moving to stronger solvents.